# How to prevent a method from being overridden in derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

How can I enforce that a base class method is not being overridden by a derived class?

Comment: Don't make it virtual in the base class? Then it can't be overridden, only overloaded. There is no direct equivalent to Java's `final` methods, if that's the question.

Comment: so without using a virtual key word we cannot make it, so how did they implemented in JAVA then

Comment: in Java, marking a method `final` forbids subclasses from implementing that method, and the compiler and/or byte code verifier will enforce this. In C++, there's no way to forbid it, it's just that by definition of "override", only virtual functions can be "overridden".

Comment: Note that there is a `final` specifier added with C++11: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16896559/1025391

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you make the method non-virtual, derived classes cannot override the method. However, in C++03 a class cannot override a method from a base class, and also *prevent* further derived classes from overriding the same method. Once the method is virtual, it stays virtual.

Comment: with C++11 you can use <code>final</code> specifier to avoid a method being overridden in derived classes

Answer (score 40):

If you are able to use the [`final`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) specifier from C++11 you can prevent derived classes from override that method. (Microsoft compilers appear to support the similar [`sealed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w2w91tf(v=vs.140).aspx) with similar semantics.)

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct base {
    // To derived class' developers: Thou shalt not override this method
    virtual void work() final {
        pre_work();
        do_work();
        post_work();
    }
    virtual void pre_work() {};
    virtual void do_work() = 0;
    virtual void post_work() {};
};

struct derived : public base {
    // this should trigger an error:
    void work() {
        std::cout << "doing derived work\n";
    }
    void do_work() {
        std::cout << "doing something really very important\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    derived d;
    d.work();
    base& b = d;
    b.work();
}
```

Here's what I get when I try to compile it:

```
$ g++ test.cc -std=c++11
test.cc:17:14: error: virtual function ‘virtual void derived::work()’
test.cc:5:22: error: overriding final function ‘virtual void base::work()’
```

Comment: Question: Why should I declare "work()" as "virtual" when I don't want that it is overridden in derived classes - why not just mark it as final?

Comment: @Sonic78 Good question! In real world code, you might have another base class to `base`, that provides a virtual function that you want to prevent to be overridden in classes deriving from your intermediate base.

Answer (score 3):

Don't make it virtual.

This won't prevent deriving from your class and hiding the function (by providing *another* member function with the same name). However, if your class is not meant to be derived anyway (no virtual destructor, no virtual member functions), that shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

well if you want to keep it public, dont declare it virtual.

EDIT: Srikanth commented wondering about overriding a private member function in a derived class.

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A(){};
    void test()
    {
        foo();
    };
private:
    virtual void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "A";   
    };
};


class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "B";   
    };
};


void test()
{
    B b;
    A& a = b;

    a.test(); // this calls the derived B::foo()

    return 0;
}`
```

Comment: Derived classes can still override virtual private member functions.

Comment: I have edited, thanx for the correction.

Comment: but how can we override a private method without making the derived a friend or decreasing the access specifier

Comment: @Srikanth, I have edited the answer and added an example code.