# Is there a way to get the negation of if a function exists for an object?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, type-traits

To determine if a function exists for a function, you can use the following:

```
template <typename...Ts>
using void_t = void;

void fn(int);

struct X {};

template <typename T, typename = void_t<decltype(fn(std::declval<T>()))>>
void fn2(T) { }

void test() {
  fn2(int(1)); // works
  //fn2(X()); // doesn't work
}
```

Now, is there a way of detecting if the `fn(T)` doesn't exist for type `T`?

Example:

```
void test2() {
  //fn2(int(1)); // doesn't work
  fn2(X()); // works
}
```

The reason for this is to define an exclusion operation so that I can define `fn2()` for both to avoid an ambiguity error.

Comment: I'd recommend wrapping the check in a type trait. Then negation is the same as any other trait.

Comment: @Quentin, fixed

Comment: Aaaaand [Clang bug](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd7152e6fdb18ab6) :| It works fine without the `void_t<>` though.

Comment: @Quentin, yeah *shrug*.  I'm currently not worried about Clang's bugs. ;)

Comment: @kabanus, edited answer to answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way of doing it is to make a type trait, as @chris said:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct fn_callable_with : std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct fn_callable_with<T, void_t<decltype(fn(std::declval<T>()))>> : std::true_type {};

// For bonus C++14 points:
// template <typename T>
// /*C++17: inline*/ constexpr bool fn_callable_with_v = fn_callable_with<T>::value;

template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<!fn_callable_with<T>::value>::type>
// C++14: template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<!fn_callable_with_v<T>>>
void fn2(T) { }
```

Comment: I've just got bitten: this does **not** work in all cases. `fn` inside the `decltype` probe is a dependent name, thus its lookup is deferred until the template's instantiation, as we need. But then, the lookup must find `fn` *via ADL*. This means that `fn`'s for fundamental types and `fn`'s from other namespaces are *not* detected if they were not already declared before the template specialization. [See live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0c35f9ce84dcbc6).

Comment: @Quentin - Well, the OP's own code conveniently defines `void fn(int)` before the template definition. So that one will be found. What you describe is a usual caveat of templates, nothing new under the sun.

Comment: @StoryTeller Just expecting the worst ;)

Comment: @Quentin - As one should :) Btw, in the link you posted, I think you uncovered compiler bugs. Those two `fn`'s ought not to be found, but they seem to be found.

Comment: @StoryTeller `fn2(X());` is okay, it gets instantiated because `fn(X)` does not exist. `fn2(int(1));`, however, should be an error since `fn(int)` exists (and thus `fn2` should SFINAE out and leave the overload set empty). But `fn(int)` is not found by `fn_callable_with` for the reason I described above, hence a false negative.

Comment: @Quentin - Got it. [I was bit by this again](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.expl.spec#7).

Comment: @Adrian - What is `x(int)` in your demo? Did you mean `fn(int)`?

Comment: @StoryTeller Holy *wow*, are they out of bullet points? This is the hairiest enumerating sentence I've seen in my life ._.

Answer (score 1):

You need another overload of `fn2`, otherwise SFINAE won't do anything useful.

```
void fn2(...) { } // called if the overload below is SFINAEd away

template <typename T, typename = void_t<decltype(fn(std::declval<T>()))>>
void fn2(T) { }
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iT78K2k3qCqZawOM)

---

The idea is that SFINAE can remove **candidates from an overload set**. If `fn2` is the only candidate, then you're going to get an hard error.

Comment: Yes, I do need to overload it, but I need to overload it when it doesn't match the one already defined.  In other words I need to define an exclusion operation so I don't get an ambiguity error, while not resulting in a hard error and keeping the type.

Comment: @Adrian, you mean that you want to get a compile-time error, if you try to overload method already had realization?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465686/how-to-prevent-a-method-from-being-overridden-in-derived-class

Comment: No compile time error.  I want a way to have a function selected if a function can be operated on an object, and I want another function selected if not.